# Using a progressbar with a method in Jax

Tags: python, jax

I am using JaX would like to use a progressbar for a class method. The method starts as following:

```
@partial(jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def _run_step(self, runner, i_step):
           ...
```

I tried adding the `scan_tqdm` decorator, but it didn't work. This happenned because the decorator works when the decorated function takes 2 inputs; an input used by the function (in my case `runner`) and a step counter for the bar (in my case `i_step`). However, in my case there is also `self`, which appears to create problems for `scan_tqdm`.

Any ideas to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
I ended up solving the problem by using `scan_tqdm` within `lax.scan` like this:

```
runner, metrics = lax.scan(
                scan_tqdm(self.config["TOTAL_STEPS"])(self._run_step),
                runner,
                jnp.arange(self.config["TOTAL_STEPS"]),
                self.config["TOTAL_STEPS"]
            )
```

Comment: I think the question misses some context to answer it more precisely, but my guess is you will need to work with a Jax callback here, see e.g. https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/external_callbacks.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up solving the problem by calling 'scan_tqdm' within 'lax.scan' (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Using scan_tqdm within lax.scan is indeed a good approach to integrate progress tracking with your method.

Another approach:

You can add @partial(scan_tqdm, 0), you’re specifying that the scan_tqdm decorator should consider the first argument (which is self) as a placeholder, allowing it to properly handle the function signature.

```
from jax.experimental.optimizers import scan_tqdm
from functools import partial

@partial(jit, static_argnums=(0,))
@partial(scan_tqdm, 0)  # Adding a placeholder for self
def _run_step(self, runner, i_step):
    # Your method implementation here
```